# Python regex matching Apache LogFormat "combinedvhost"

Tags: python, regex

```
LogFormat "%v %a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combinedvhost
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access_log" combinedvhost
```

I have an apache configuration producing an access_log with above log format. I'm trying to create a python (2.7.13) regex that creates groups (ignoring HTTP method and HTTP version).

Below is my regex so far:

```
(?P<host>.*)\s+(?P<ip>\S+)\s+-\s+-\s+\[(?P<date>\S+)\s+(?P<timezone>.*)\]\s+"\S+\s+(?P<path>\S+)(?:\?(?P<querystring>\S+))?\s+\S+"\s+(?P<status>\S+)\s+(?P<length>\S+)\s+"(?P<referrer>.*)"\s+"(?P<user_agent>.*)"\s+
```

My problem is the first log line where the expected result is `path = /` and `querystring = simplode_ajax=true&simplode_query%5Border%5D=DESC`. It seams like my path group is matching to greedy though as it returns `querystring = None` and the entire string as `path` instead...

I was testing above regex and below log at http://pythex.org.

```
default 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:18 -0800] "GET /?simplode_ajax=true&simplode_query%5Border%5D=DESC HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://www.xxx.xx/xxx/xx/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
default 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:20 -0800] "GET /xxx/xx/06/22/xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11098 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
www.xxx.xx 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:20 -0800] "POST /xxxxxx.php HTTP/1.1" 200 370 "-" "-"
default 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:23 -0800] "GET /blog/xxx/01/22/xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14404 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
www.xxx.xx 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:24 -0800] "GET /blog/xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21901 "https://www.codingmerc.com/blog/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"
www.xxx.xx 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:25 -0800] "POST /xxxxx.php HTTP/1.1" 200 370 "-" "-"
www.xxx.xx 1.2.3.4 - - [05/Jan/2017:10:56:29 -0800] "GET /blog/xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13831 "https://www.xxx.xx/blog/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you simply make your path group non greedy:
replace`+` by `+?`

Comment: Sheesh, it was that simple, huh? :)